# gitignore not working .env file getting updated

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this entry in my gitignore file in laravel

```
/vendor
.env
```

but sometimes .env file also gets updated on live server

i ran this command on my local branch :

```
git rm .env --cached
```

but after that this error is there : `fatal: pathspec '.env' did not match any files`

Answer (score 2):

To check if your `.env` file is versioned in your current branch, run :

```
git ls-tree HEAD .env
```

If you see no output, then the file isn't tracked in your current branch.

---

Since `git rm --cached .env` failed, your `.env` file is probably not versioned.

Check what other elements in your deploy procedure may modify your `.env` file.

Comment: I would probably go with `git ls-files .env` to determine whether the files is tracked, since it shows whether the path is in the index.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio : you're right. Since the OP seems to have issues with what gets deployed to his server, I was guiding him to spot the file in the current *commit*

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error once. To fix it, you can use the following steps:

1. Check if the `.env` file is tracked by Git using the `git ls-files` command. If it is not, then you have already removed it from Git.
2. Run the `git rm -r --cached env` command to remove the `.env` file from your remote Git repository.
3. If the `.env` file is still showing up in your GitHub repository, then you are probably not on the `master` branch in your local repository. Checkout to the your main branch where you made the changes and repeat steps 2 and 3.
4. If you want, you can merge the changes from your newly edited branch to your default branch.